# Who are Gaston's "five hangers-on"?

Tags: soundtrack, beauty-and-the-beast-2017

In the song "Gaston", it is said that the eponymous character has "five hangers-on". I imagine LeFou, Tom, Dick and Stanley are part of them?

Who are Gaston's 'five hangers-on'?

Comment: Note this is originally from the extended original song, which wasn't used in the original cartoon movie. Seems like they added it to the live action film? I don't recall hearing it though.

Comment: Here are the full lyrics to the mentioned version of the song: http://www.fpx.de/fp/Disney/Lyrics/BeautyAndTheBeast.html#Gaston

Answer (score -1):

Funny story with this one. The Five hangers-on are LeFou, Tom, Dick, Stanley, and the nameless elderly man that sings along too. However, they get rid of the elderly man in the live action version and keep the lyric the same, which makes no sense, as it would be four hangers-on without the elderly man. But yeah, there's the answer.